# install nodejs and npm on ubuntu 21.10, install sucessful but showing wrong version with "node -v"

Tags: node.js

I am new to js and wanted to install nodejs LTS version and npm on ubuntu 21.10. So, I followed the nodesources repository install instructions and it had stated to use the install script for LTS and it worked fine as I followed the same instructions mentioned in it.

But, after installation of the nodejs package, when I try to check the node -v: it shows as 12.x.x, while the latest LTS version for nodejs is 16.x.x. I did not understand why this is happening and what is the solution for this?

P.S: I have mentioned the commands that I had used for installation of nodejs LTS 16.x.x, and the site link is this: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

cmd:

```
Node.js LTS (v16.x):

# Using Ubuntu
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Please note: I have not installed the optional build tools yet and not the npm as well. I'm confused on what to do now...

Comment: a lot of solutions here https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1157#issuecomment-1159831586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another the most simple NodeJS version manager is the one that created by tj
it's callend 'n'

https://github.com/tj/n

[N in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RohL9.gif)

you can install it as easy as :

install NPM first :

```
$ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tj/n/master/bin/n -o n
bash n lts
```

Now node and npm are available, installing n :

```
$ npm install -g n
```

then if you want to install the LTS version of NodeJS. just use this command :

```
$ n lts
```

or if you want the latest version of NodeJS

```
$ n latest
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is installing `nvm`, which comes with the additional advantage of being able to install several different versions of `node` and switching between them easily:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

Once installed, in some occasions you have to close the terminal and reopen it for the `nvm` command to work. From then on, simply install the version you need:

```bash
nvm install lts
```

or a specific version:

```bash
nvm install 14.7.0 # or 16.3.0, 12.22.1, etc
```

With this single command, it installs together the corresponding `npm` version compatible with the `node` being installed, so you don't have to worry about it. To switch between versions, just:

```bash
nvm use 14.7.0 # or 16.3.0, 12.22.1, etc
```